# How to change values when satisfying two conditions in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am kind of stuck, I want to change the value to 0 when if the condition is satisfy.

Here is the example of dataframe.

```
Time            Percent      energy
2020-11-01         40         200
2020-11-01         50         150
2020-11-02         37         205
2020-11-05         51         222
2020-11-07         80         189
2020-11-11         55         225
2020-11-01         30         150
2020-11-05         53         251
2020-11-06         45         222
2020-11-22         62         125
2020-11-25         53         255
```

so I want to change the energy to 0 if percent is smaller than 41 and energy is smaller than 207.

Here is the desired output.

```
Time            Percent      energy
2020-11-01         40          0
2020-11-01         50         150
2020-11-02         37          0
2020-11-05         51         222
2020-11-07         80         189
2020-11-11         55         225
2020-11-01         30          0
2020-11-05         53         251
2020-11-06         45         222
2020-11-22         62         125
2020-11-25         53         255
```

I've try to run below code but some how it all change values to 0 which is smaller than 207.

```
df['energy']=np.where((df['percent]>41) & ~(df['energy'] >207), 0, df['energy'])
```

can someone please advise me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You were close,  think about the logic, you had the not and > in the right place but remember not greater than is less than.

```
df['energy'] = np.where(((df['percent']<41) & (df['energy'] <207)), 0, df['energy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add an attempt without numpy. By using the apply-method with a lambda fucntion.

```
df['energy'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row['Percent'] < 41 and row['energy'] < 207 else row['Percent'], axis=1)
```